# Failed to load dynlib/dll - \\bin\\libeay32'. Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen

Tags: python, pycharm, conda

I'm attempting to create a new Conda environment in Pycharm. But I keep getting the following error in Pycharm.

```
'C:\\Users\\*****\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI312082\\Library\\bin\\libeay32'. Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

I'm running the latest version of PyCharm on Windows 10 64 Bit with Python 3.5.

Comment: Which Conda version? What did you do in order to create the environment?

Comment: I've got exact same problem conda 4.8.2, python 3.7. This is only happening only if I specify Python version explicitly though. Otherwise the env gets created without any issues

Comment: I'm not sure that `_conda.exe` should be used instead of `conda.exe`, please try to specify `conda.exe` as conda binary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same problem:
In the Project Interpreter settings - Conda Interpreter - New Interpreter 
I originally specified the conda executable path as C:\Program_Files\Anaconda3_conda.exe and got the Failed to load error.
After searching I changed this to C:\Program_Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
and it all worked.